# using simple html dom to scrape

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape some content using simple_html_dom without luck.

I am trying to grab the title, image path and the link and display it.

The HTML structure is:

```
<div class="article_item clearfix">
<h2 class="title"><a href="http://www.demodomain/articleid=1">My amazing Title</a></h2>
<p class="date">September 22 2014</p>
<p class="image_left">
<a href="http://www.demodomain/articleid=1">
<img src="http://www.demodomain/photos/cef78533cd5.jpg" alt="My amazing post ">
</a>
</p>
<p>This is a demo description<strong>of this amazing</strong> article</p>
<p class="more"><a href="http://www.demodomain/articleid=1" class="blued_links">Read more...</a></p>
</div>
```

My code so far:

```
foreach($html->find('article_item') as $article) {
    $item['title']   = $article->find('.title, a', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['thumb']  = $article->find('.image_left img', 0)->src;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('p', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['url'] = $article->find('.more, a', 0)->plaintext;
       


echo 'Title: ' . $item['title'];
echo "</br>";
echo "image url: " . $item['thumb'];
echo "</br>";
echo "Description: " . $item['details'];
echo "</br>";
echo "Read More Url: " . $item['url'];
}



// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

Comment: So whats not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: This isn't even a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state whats not working but consider this example:

```
foreach($html->find('div.article_item') as $div) {
                 //  ^ point to div tag with class name article_item
    $title = $div->find('h2.title a ', 0)->innertext;
                     // ^ target the h2 tag with class title with child anchor
                     // just same as accessing dom with jquery
    $thumb = $div->find('p.image_left img ', 0)->src;
    $details = $div->children(3)->plaintext;
    // $url = $div->find('p.more', 0)->plaintext;
    $url = $div->find('p.more a', 0)->href;

    echo $title . '<br/>';
    echo $thumb . '<br/>';
    echo $details . '<br/>';
    echo $url . '<br/>';
}
```

Basically, this is just the same as selecting selectors.

Comment: Great Mr. Ghost... Thank you a lot!!! From $url i need to take the a href link. How is this possible please?

Comment: @IreneT. made the revision, try it again

Comment: @IreneT. sure no prob glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this

```
$item['title']   = $article->find('h2.title')->plaintext;
$item['thumb']  = $article->find('p.image_left')->find('img')->src;
```